# error: Too few argument to function

Tags: c++, compilation

I know that there is a lot of similar questions, but I'm too new. so my problem is that I have  to do a makefile and compile my project, but at some point it returns error.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "SquareRootCalculation.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int number = atoi(argv[0]);
    int th = atoi(argv[1]);
    float result = SquareRoot(number, th);
return 0;
}
```

InitialGuess.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int InitialGuess(int number)
{
   float numberLength = 0;
for(; number != 0; number /= 10, numberLength++);
float n = nearbyint(sqrt(numberLength));
float y = numberLength * pow(10, n);
return  0;
}
```

SqrtCalc.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "InitialGuess.h"
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int SquareRoot(int number, int th, float y)
{
int initialGuess = InitialGuess(y);
float x = initialGuess;
 for (int k=1; k< th; ++k)
    {
        x = (x + (number / x ))/2; 
    }
cout<<x;    
 return 0;
}
```

also I have InitialGuess.h

```
int InitialGuess(int number, float y);
```

and sqrtcalc.h

```
int SquareRoot(int number, int th);
```

and a makefile

```
all:
g++ Main.cpp InitialGuess.cpp SquareRootCalculation.cpp -o FR
```

It returns an error

```
InitialGuess.h 1 In function 'int SquareRoot (int,int,float)'
InitialGuess.h "too few arguments 'int InitialGuess(int, float)'
```

SqrtCalc 7 error at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error is self explanatory:

in .h file you defined `int InitialGuess(int number, float y);` - with 2 arguments, but in .cpp file `int InitialGuess(int number)` - with one

the same problem with `SquareRoot` function

Answer (score 2):

This is the declaration of your function:

```
int SquareRoot(int number, int th, float y)
```

and this is how you called it:

```
SquareRoot(number, th);
```

You're missing the third argument.

Moreover, `InitialGuess` takes two arguments but you have it one.